# Selenium - parallel execution single test case multiple browsers

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

Please help me out that How to run single test simultaneously in multiple browser. Where that single test contains 100 accounts verification. We have to run 10 account verification in one browser and other 10 in another browser like that.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. For your question to be answered please add examples and enough information so it can be reproduced by others. You can review suggestions on how to ask a good question on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .